# Rails 6.0 Migration file convert to integer as per Postgres preference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, rails-migrations

Beginner here, deploying to Heroku. Sqlite3 in dev, PG in production.

Test environment has all migrations running successfully at this point.

I am trying to deploy to Heroku. The git works fine. But when I run `heroku run rails db:migrate` I get the following error

```
== 20210116010525 ChangeMediaLinksRefToInteger: migrating =====================
-- change_column(:media_links, :media_category_id, :integer)
D, [2021-01-16T19:33:04.056111 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.4ms)  BEGIN
D, [2021-01-16T19:33:04.060684 #4] DEBUG -- :    (4.1ms)  ALTER TABLE "media_links" ALTER COLUMN "media_category_id" TYPE integer
D, [2021-01-16T19:33:04.066364 #4] DEBUG -- :    (5.0ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2021-01-16T19:33:04.072867 #4] DEBUG -- :    (6.0ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(4856957400867515370)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "media_category_id" cannot be cast automatically to type integer
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING media_category_id::integer".
```

Note: This migration was an error correction of my own making earlier where I accidentaly set the 'media_category_id' to be a string. I created this migration to change the column from string to integer. Migration file :

```
class ChangeMediaLinksRefToInteger < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    change_column :media_links, :media_category_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Can **update this migration** file or should I **create a new** one?
Is this what Heroku is telling me to do?

```
class ChangeMediaLinksRefToInteger < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    change_column :media_links, "USING media_category_id::integer"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your migration failed you can edit the migration to what Heroku recommended.

If the migration had ran successfully and you wanted to edit it, you could rollback the migration `./bin/rails db:rollback` then edit the file, and then run the migrations again.

If you wanted to change a migration that is already deployed to a common test environment or to PreProd/Prod, then it is best to create a new migration to apply the changes on top.

This is what worked for me:

```
change_column :orders, :pay_type, "integer USING NULLIF(pay_type, '')::int"
```

Comment: so for me it should be    `change_column :media_links, :media_category_id, "integer USING NULLIF(media_category_id, '')::int"    is that correct?

Comment: Now I'm getting this : Error: Cannot run more than 1 Free size dynos. I presume I've used up all free attempts within the 24h cycle? I'll try again tomorrow.